# Unable to mkdir on a single node Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-desktop

This

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

suggests doing:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/data`

on a single node cluster.

Using a single node Kubernetes cluster (Kubernetes on Docker Desktop) I get:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/data
bash: sudo: command not found
```

Doing

```
mkdir /mnt/data
```

I get:

```
mkdir: can't create directory '/mnt/data': Read-only file system
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That seems like an odd suggestion; I'd normally expect a _persistent volume provisioner_ to create the storage for you.  Where are you typing these commands?  Are you already root (so you don't need `sudo`)?  Is there a programming component to this question?

Comment: From https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/ (see start)

Comment: assuming you are using minikube, so by default, it uses docker driver for running minikube, so it is running it in a container. You recreate your minikube cluster with using VM, check https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/virtualbox/

Comment: @Snowcrash could you confirm if you are using minikube ?

Comment: Docker-desktop - it turned out that was the issue. All fine with minikube.